# Tkinter child widgets don't trigger <Leave> on parent

Tags: python, tkinter

When the mouse moves from a parent widget into a child widget and the parent has a `<Leave>` binding the event is never triggered due to the mouse not actually leaving the bounds of the parent. It is also the same for `<Enter>` when the mouse outside the child widget yet remains in the parent.

Is there another way to trigger an event when the mouse moves to and from a child widget.

In the code below the bottom box should always match the colour of the box the mouse is over, when moving from green to purple the `<Enter>` event is triggered but the `<Leave>` event is never triggered from the green box, similar when moving from purple back to green the `<Leave>` event is triggered on purple (defaulting the box white) but the `<Enter>` event is never triggered on the green box.

```py
from tkinter import *

class tracer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.widgets = {}
        self.active = None
        self.marker = None
    def add_w(self, c, w):
        self.widgets[c] = w
    def add_marker(self, w):
        self.marker = w
    def set_active(self, event, c):
        print(f"setting {c} active")
        if c in self.widgets:
            self.active = self.widgets[c]
            self.marker.configure(bg=c)
        print(f"{self.active} is now active")
    def set_inactive(self, event, c):
        print(f"setting {c} inactive")
        if c in self.widgets and self.active == self.widgets[c]:
            self.active = None
            self.marker.configure(bg="white")
        print(f"Nothing should be active {self.active}")

t = tracer()
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400+100+100")
box1 = Frame(root, bg="red")
box1.pack(fill=BOTH,side=TOP,expand=1)
box2 = Frame(root, bg="green")
box2.pack(fill=BOTH,side=TOP,expand=1)
sub_box2 = Frame(box2, bg="purple")
sub_box2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=30, pady=30)

box3 = Frame(root, bg="white", borderwidth=2)
box3.pack(fill=BOTH,side=TOP,expand=1)

t.add_w("red", box1)
t.add_w("green", box2)
t.add_w("purple", sub_box2)
t.add_marker(box3)
box1.bind("<Enter>", lambda e=Event(), c="red", w=box1:t.set_active(e, c))
box2.bind("<Enter>", lambda e=Event(), c="green", w=box2:t.set_active(e, c))
sub_box2.bind("<Enter>", lambda e=Event(), c="purple", w=box2:t.set_active(e, c))

box1.bind("<Leave>", lambda e=Event(), c="red":t.set_inactive(e, c))
box2.bind("<Leave>", lambda e=Event(), c="green":t.set_inactive(e, c))
sub_box2.bind("<Leave>", lambda e=Event(), c="purple":t.set_inactive(e, c))

root.mainloop()
```

I need this to determine when the mouse is over a scrollable child widget of a scrollable parent widget as the mousewheel isn't handled by Tkinter natively.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there another way to trigger an event when the mouse moves to and from a child widget.

You could bind on `<Motion>` and track which widget is under the mouse, and then generate a custom event when the current widget changes.

For example:

```
def generate_events(event):
    global current_widget
    if current_widget != event.widget:
        current_widget.event_generate("<<Leave>>")
        current_widget = event.widget
        event.widget.event_generate("<<Enter>>")

current_widget = root
root.bind_all("<Motion>", generate_events)
```

You can then bind to the custom `<<Enter>>` and `<<Leave>>` events to be notified when a widget becomes the one under the cursor.

```
def gain_focus(event):
    print(f"gain focus: {event.widget}")

def lose_focus(event):
    print(f"lose focus: {event.widget}")

root.bind_all("<<Enter>>", gain_focus)
root.bind_all("<<Leave>>", lose_focus)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events one way is to keep track of the widgets that the mouse enters and leaves in a deque instead. The below code keeps track of the highlighted widgets in the correct way.

```
from collections import deque

class tracer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.widgets = deque()

    def set_active(self, event, c):
        if len(self.widgets) > 0:
            last_widget, lc = self.widgets[-1]
            last_widget.configure(bg=lc)
        self.widgets.append((event.widget, c))
        event.widget.configure(bg = "white")

    def set_inactive(self, event, c):
        last_widget, c = self.widgets.pop()
        last_widget.configure(bg=c)
        if len(self.widgets) > 0:
            current_widget, c = self.widgets[-1]
            current_widget.configure(bg="white")
```

I have tested it with multiple widgets containing three levels of widgets and it seems consistent with the events firing in the correct order and the deque keeping track correctly. I even paused the program on the inner widget and when moving to debugger and resuming the program it kept track of the leave events correctly.

There is some weirdness on drag and drop where it fails, but should be possible to overcome.